# Touch functionality on 3.5" LCD Touchscreen not working

Tags: rpi.gpio, touchscreen

I have loaded the Raspbian image onto my LCD Touchscreen for the Rasp Pi. However, the touch facility does not work. The display is there but no touch.
Can anyone help?

I am using the Waveshare 3.5" LCD Touchscreen. I have downloaded and extracted and written the Raspbian image as per Waveshare's installation process. I have enabled the SPI kernel and ran any updates.

The Raspbian display is there on the LCD Touchscreen but the only way to navigate around the Desktop environment is through attaching a mouse. The pen stylus, or any touch facility, is not being activated at all.

Comment: Give us a little more info. Like link of touchscreen that you're using and what you've tried so far. That would help ppl debugging your issue.

Comment: Hello. I am using the [Waveshare] (http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/3.5inch_RPi_LCD_(A)) 3.5" LCD Touchscreen. I have downloaded and extracted and written the Raspbian image as per Waveshare's installation process. I have enabled the SPI kernel and ran any updates.

Comment: Is it that touch is getting detected on wrong coordinates or it is not working at all ?

Comment: Try saving calibration data in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-calibration.conf` instead of what is given in that guide and reboot. Hope it helps.

Comment: The Raspbian display is there on the LCD Touchscreen but the only way to navigate around the Desktop environment is through attaching a mouse. The pen stylus, or any touch facility, is not being activated at all

Comment: Hi @dastaan Can you offer any assistance with my problem with the touch facility not working on my Waveshare 3.5" LCD Touchscreen for the Raspberry Pi please?

Comment: To be frank, I've not used this sort of touch screens and hence can't offer any assistance except for a few basic things as mentioned above in my comments.

Answer (score 0):

Never got a fix from Waveshare so opted for a different LCD and cut costs. For info, decided to use a Raspberry PI official LCD which is working and fine. http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/graphics-display-development-kits/1115927/[RaspberryPiLCD](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/graphics-display-development-kits/1115927/)

Comment: Welcome to the RPi flavored version of StackExchange. In general, link only answers are discouraged here as they are subject to link rot. A better answer would summarize the the main points here, while maintaining the link out.